# Hide PHP-Scriptname from URL (Shorten URL)

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I'm currently working on a huge school project and got to a point where I'd actually need some help.

My website has a script called "page.php" in the root directory. This script uses a get parameter ("l", 6 character long, string) - so the url would be something like that: mysite.com/page.php?l=abcdef

Now I'd like to be able to make the link look like that: mysite.com/abcdef

Would something like that be possible? If yes, how?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a better question for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This isn't done in PHP, it's done in the web site's rewrite rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so using .htaccess file in your root directory. All requests to your domain (except known files and directories) will be routed to page.php

```
DirectoryIndex page.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/page.php?l=$1 [R=301,L]
```

In page.php do catch it with $_GET['page']

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But the /index.php file does also get redirected if I do it like this... :(

Comment: you didn't mention index.php . You don't need index, with what you are trying to achieve. If $_GET['page'] is empty, or '/', then it is your home page, include your index or do whatever your logic there.

Comment: Amazing... Thank you so much! Works :)

Comment: Good luck. BTW, why not to try learn a PHP framework, will be easier for you in the long run, and you will learn best practices. Once you get experienced you could write your own code.